# How to prove that a straight line is an infinite set of points?

Tags: geometry

From the basic elementary level when we start reading geometry we get this idea developed in us that a straight line is the conjuction of infinite points.but how to prove this?  I mean is this an axiom or its provable?

Comment: Does every pair of points have a mid point?

Comment: Obviously theoretically it should have

Comment: Well, then obviously there are an infinite number of points.

Comment: According to me a line is a set of infinite no of points connected together.

Comment: Then you need to look at your axioms.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are such things as ["finite geometries"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry) (such as the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane)). Of course, these are meant to satisfy an extremely limited set of axioms. As @copper.hat suggests, you should be clear about the list of axioms you wish to consider, to see what's needed to guarantee an infinitude of points.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected together"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different foundations of geometry. Regarding the infinitude of the points of a straight line, I think, the following axioms of Ordered Geometry are the best to shape intuition:

- We do not define what a point is. But we will use capital letters to denote these undefined objects. We do not define what intermediacy is. We just say that triplets of our undefined points may be in intermediacy relation.
- Definition: If $[APB]$ then we say that $P$ is in  between $A$ and $B$.
- Axiom 1: There are at least two distinct points.
- Axiom 2: If $A$ and $B$ are two distinct points, there is at least one point $P$ for which $[ABP]$.
- Axiom 3: If [ABC], then $A$ and $C$ are distinct.
- Axiom 4: If $[ABC]$ then $[CBA]$ an not $[CAB]$.
- Theorem: (1) If $[ABC]$ then not $[CAB]$. (2) If $[ABC]$ then $A$, $B$, $C$ are distinct.
- Definition: If $A$ and $B$ are two distinct points then all the points $P$ for which either $[APB]$ or $[PAB]$ or $[ABP]$ form a line.
- Theorem: A line contains infinitely many points. Proof: There is at least one line because there are at least two points. The second axiom says that besides the two points defining the line the line has further points. Repeated application of of Axiom 2 shows that a line has infinitely many points.
- The axioms I use are the first two axioms of the Pasch-Veblen foundation of ordered geometry.
- Reference: Coxeter: Introduction to geometry.

Comment: Importantly, you need that the axiom that *at most one* of $[A,B,P]$, $[A,P,B]$, and $[P,A,B]$ hold for a particular trio of points $A$, $B$, $C$. (Otherwise, you get "circularity", and your argument doesn't necessarily hold. See my comment under Jaood's answer.)

Comment: @Blue: This is why I put the $\cdots$ up there. This is sort of a race. I hate that. I had to act fast. Anybody: Please read Coxeter's Foundation; namly Ch. 12.2. "Intermediacy". I love the Pasch-Veblen foundation.

Comment: When you fill-in the "...", I'll remove my comment. :)

Comment: @Blue: OK. But you will not have to remove your comments. I appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Take your endpoints, call them $S$ and $E$. Pick some point between $S$ and $E$, let us call it $M$. Then, pick a point between $S$ and $M$. Call it $M_2$. Pick a point between $S$ and $M_2$ ....

If you can keep going like that, it is easy to see that the line must have infinite points... *and you **can** keep going on like that.* The numbers don't just end.

Comment: Ok I understand your point and I can make a perceptive view about it, but is there is theorem based proof of it. I mean if I am solving it I can't assume it as it will be a particular case basis proof

Comment: @Demietra95, to have a theorem, you need to have axioms, somewhere to start. What are your axioms? How do you define a line? Is a line the like the real number line, or is it something else?

Comment: Alright. Now I am getting the point. Thanks a lot. But in this case if I have got only the this question what should be my approach to start the problems with and what axioms should I choose!? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: *"... and you **can** keep going on like that."* Whether this leads to an infinitude of points depends on your axioms. My universe might consist of exactly three points, $A$, $B$, $C$, where I declare each one to be "between" (or even "the midpoint of") the other two. In this case, your construction does not provide infinitely-many points; it just cycles through the set $\{A, B, C\}$ over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

any point, y, on line in 2d cartesian space can satisfy following equation:

y = a*x + b, where a and b are constant real numbers, and x is real number with range (-inf, +inf)

because x has infinite range, so y has inf range.

this prove line has infinite number of points

Comment: Understood the solution. Thanks

Comment: Of course, this *assumes* a correspondence between geometric lines and algebraic linear equations of real-number variables. There are geometries with no such correspondence. As mentioned by myself and others, one must be clear about the axioms system being used.

Answer (score 0):

You might know the equation of a straight line through 2 points which is: $$y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$$
From that we can see that there are infinite solutions to satisfy this equation which proves that a straight line contains infinite points.

Comment: Again a good logic. Thanks.

Comment: At your pleasure

Comment: See my comment under @lixu's answer.